# Delete single event from recursive event using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to delete the single-day event from a recursive event using Microsoft Graph API? if it is possible to delete please share a useful link

Comment: You can try listing all instances using this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Try using the id of the required instance and send Delete request.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I got an empty value array in response when I run my api link in Microsoft graph explorer

Comment: Did it got deleted?

Comment: still not delete

Comment: On using which call are you getting empty array?

Comment: `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/id/instances?startDateTime=2021-02-18T11:54:27&endDateTime=2021-02-18T11:54:27` When I am call this then show empty array

Comment: You need to use GRAPH API, not outlook. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/id/instances?startDateTime=2021-02-18T11:54:27&endDateTime=2021-02-18T11:54:27`. See if it works.

Comment: still not working

Comment: See if that particular event is present in that timeframe or not.

Comment: It's working now.. issue in the start date and end date

Comment: Glad to here that it's working. Please accept the answer so that it could be helpful to others who look for the same issue :)-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the instances using the below API call. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/id/instances?startDateTime=&endDateTime=`

Try using the id of the required instance and send Delete request.